# Testar se a imagem existe

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Pessoal utilizo o Intervention no Laravel 5.5 e utilizo as rotas dele com os filtros para gerar as imagens dinamicamente. Gostaria de saber como eu posso testar na classe do filtro e a imagem que passei ela existe no disco, caso não eu carrego uma imagem padrão do site. Obrigado

Comment: Só php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php ou http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

Comment: @Miguel eu tentei estes 2 métodos, mas como estam em servidores diferentes eles não funcionam. As imagens estam no servidor do backend e o frontend esta em outro servidor.

Comment: Você tem que alterar sua pergunta dizendo que as imagens estão em locais diferentes e que acessa da.seguinte.forma tem como editar?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic então acho que a pergunta esta correta. Pois o filtro esta no mesmo servidor que as imagens. Mas o servidor que vai acessar as imagens via URL esta em outra maquina. Esta resposta que dei abaixo foi a forma que achei no servidor de Frontend. Mas vou postar agora a forma que consegui fazer direto no servidor das imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando uma nova rota onde eu checo se o arquivo existe e se não existe eu coloco o arquivo padrão e depois encaminho para a rota padrão do Intervention. Deu certinho Desta forma.
Definição da rota:

```
Route::get('/imagecache/{template}/{filename}', 'ApiController@imagecache')->where('filename','[ \w\\.\\/\\-\\@\(\)]+');
```

Controller da rota:

```
public function imagecache($template, $filename)
{
    if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists($filename)){
        $filename='images/noimage.jpg';
    }
    return response()->redirectTo('/imagecache/'.$template.'/'.$filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o melhor jeito mas fiz assim:

```
@if(strtoupper($file_headers = @get_headers('http://www.meuservidor.com.br/miniatura/'.$item['imagem'])[0])=='HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
```

Assim funcionou perfeitamente, mas com certeza tem o custo de 1 conexão a mais com o servidor por imagem. Se alguém souber um jeito melhor gostaria de saber. Principalmente se tiver como fazer isto direto no servidor de imagem seria TOP. Obrigado